# call a bash script from a bash script and wait for it to get over and continue

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I just want to execute the "CloneBUildInstall.sh", "MonkeyTest.sh" and"SilentException.sh"..
i dont wont to source it. How can i simply execute it.

```
adb devices > output.txt
```

## call the scripts

```
while :
do
. CloneBuildInstall.sh
```

## Do not source. Just execute...how can i do that?

```
    echo "Clone, Build and Install script is finished."

. MonkeyTest.sh & . SilentException.sh &
    echo "Monkey Test script and Silent Exception is finished."
done
```

Comment: try `bash CloneBuildInstall.sh`

Comment: @AvinashRaj and it will wait for that to run and then execute?

Answer (score 0):

Besides calling them again with a binary of the shell, you can run them in a subshell which apparently is easier and cleaner:

```
( . MonkeyTest.sh )
( . SilentException.sh )
```

And if you plan to run them in parallel, waiting for them to finish would be complex.

```
( . MonkeyTest.sh ) &
MPID=$!
( . SilentException.sh ) &
SPID=$!

wait "$MPID"; wait "$SPID"  ## Just basic.
```

Comment: but source and . has the same meaning...i just want to execute CloneBuildInstall.sh and wait until its over and continue from where it was.

Comment: @user3738506 `source`-ing on the same context (not on a subshell) alters the environment of the shell and affects it. But running it on a subshell runs it on a different process - and similar to running `sh /path/to/your/script.sh` only that with the subshell method, you're sure that you're running the same shell.

Comment: so . MonkeyTest.sh is simply executing it?...not sourcing?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to specify it the same way you would on the command line, but that would require a relative path to where you are running the command from.

```
./MonkeyTest.sh && ./SilentException.sh
```

Another way would be to hardcode the full path.

```
/full/path/to/MonkeyTest.sh && /full/path/to/SilentException.sh
```

Comment: but source and . has the same meaning...i just want to execute CloneBuildInstall.sh and wait until its over and continue from where it was.

Comment: @user3738506 sourcing - `. CloneBuildInstall.sh`, executing - `./CloneBuildInstall.sh`. I think you get the difference.

Comment: but then this script has launched them in background. They have not finished. I want to know when the script finishes so that i can do other task

Comment: @user3738506, No, the script does not run them in the background, unless `MonkeyTest.sh` or `SilentException.sh` are written to start up background processes by themselves.

Comment: `&&` != `&`. `x && y` runs `x`, then only runs `y` if `x` succeeds.

Comment: yes, the MonkeyTest.sh will have android monkey test case...whcih will run n number of events on a package and trace the log it if crashes...so i want to make sure when monkey test is over it should come back to this script and continue